# Change Bottom Bar icon size android

Tags: android, navigation, bottombar

I am using https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar library to make my  bottom bar 
for android but i can't change the size of the icons , any idea how to make them small ?

[image: Android Bottom Bar]

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="ytstudios.wall.plus.MainActivity"
android:background="@color/colorAccent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="8dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottom_tabs"
    app:bb_inActiveTabColor="@color/tabSelected"
    app:bb_inActiveTabAlpha="0.2"
    app:bb_behavior="iconsOnly"
    app:bb_activeTabColor="@color/tabSelected">
</com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be use [Android Asset Studio tool](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=32&padding=8&color=rgba(0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.54)&name=ic_ac_unit) to convert your icons according to your size 

As you will reduce **asset size** in the tool your icon will be reduced in size and will be displayed correctly.